# Why can't I install react-dom@experimental?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to try out some of the new Concurrent Mode features in React 18. The official documentation, as well as several articles, claim that you just need to install `react@experimental react-dom@experimental`. I have done so but I am met with the following error:

```
Property 'unstable_createRoot' does not exist on type 'typeof import("C:/my-app/node_modules/@types/react-dom/index")'.  TS2339

  > 10 | ReactDOM.unstable_createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
       |          ^
```

This is my trying to add this import to an existing project that is already working, not a new project from scratch

EDIT2: Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { App } from "./App";

ReactDOM.unstable_createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You can install it, but you also need to use the experimental _types_: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/experimental.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

That's a Typescript error/warning. (If you are not using Typescript, it's your editor using it behind the scenes.)

Your `@types/react` package doesn't have the unreleased experimental function you're trying to use.

See the comments in https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/experimental.d.ts#L2 to see how to bring the experimental bits into scope.

Comment: Tried the suggestions in the comments you linked. no success